# How to update list using linq in c#

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list of Students in cache, and I wants to update an item, how can i do that.

```
public class Student
{
    int id;
    string name;
    string address;
}

public void updateStudent(Student st)
{
    var student = _cache.Get(CacheVariable.cache_data_student) as List<Student>;
    //How to update student.
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with update? Please try to describe the desired behaviour.

Comment: Actually there is no `Update` method, and i want to update the item that is passed to `updateStudent` function.

Comment: You need to implement your own update method to student by updating all the required properties.

Comment: I don not know how I can implement, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Student
{
    int id;
    string name;
    string address;
}

public void updateStudent(Student st)
{
    var student = _cache.Get(CacheVariable.cache_data_student) as List<Student>;

    //First look for the st in Student list, you need the id field or primary key
    var s = student.Where(x => x.idField == st.idField).FirstOrDefault();
    s = st;
    //student = st;//student.Update(st); //Not working. Only pass the value
}
```

Comment: `student` is the list of students and `st` is just an item of student, how can i set `student =  st`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it with a small query.

First Find this updated student is who?

And Find this student's place from List

Then Change This Place with new Value

```
        var student = _cache.Get(CacheVariable.cache_data_student) as List<Student>;
       Student findStudent = student.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id == st.Id); 
        int id = student.IndexOf(y);
        student[id] = st;
```

or if you want you can use another thing for last row like :

```
student[id] = new Student()
{

id = x,

name = "y",

address = "z"

};
```

Probably there is a better solution for this situation but I don't know. I think this could be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Since the ID should be the unique identifier, use LINQ to get the student to update:

```
public void updateStudent(Student st)
{
    Student studentToUpdate = _cache.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id == st.id)
    studentToUpdate?.Update(st);
}
```

To update your student you need to implement your own method. Just set the properties like

```
public class Student
{
    public int id { get; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }

    public void Update(Student st)
    {
        this.name = st.name;
        this.address = st.address;
    }
}
```